# Clearing a Query String

Tags: php

I notice that if I call a page with a query string that has an action=[some_function], then refreshing the page loads the page again with the same query string.  I'm not able to do anything in the page PHP to clear that query string before refreshing the page, like doing an `unset($_GET)` or a `$_GET[action'] = ''`;   Is there a way I can change the query string programatically so the next refresh doesn't run the function again?

Comment: Use a seperate script rather than the same script to process the submit

Comment: If your function will cause problems if it runs again, it sounds like POSTing the action may be more appropriate than GET with a query string.

Answer (score 2):

After doing the processing you need with those variables in the query string, redirect back to the same page with the query string stripped from the URL.

Note that you have to do this BEFORE you display anything on the page the first time it loads (with the query string).

Here's a simple version of what that might look like ...

```
<?php

if (isset[$_GET['action'])
{
  // Process your query string here

  $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // get current page URL
  $uri = strtok( $uri, '?' ); // remove query string
  header("Location: {$uri}"); // redirect

  exit;
}

// Display the page here
```